# My AZURE account wont allow me to create a VM then gives me a cryptic error

Tags: azure

I keep getting this error , I have tried the smallest HDD drive I can using Win 2019 but the free Student subscription just wont work?

```
The template deployment failed with error: 'The resource with id: '/subscriptions/0f190a1a-ca9f-40c7-b0eb-45b259667b98/resourceGroups/webGroup1/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/web' failed validation with message: 'The requested size for resource '/subscriptions/0f190a1a-ca9f-40c7-b0eb-45b259667b98/resourceGroups/webGroup1/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/web' is currently not available in location 'eastus' zones '' for subscription '0f190a1a-ca9f-40c7-b0eb-45b259667b98'. Please try another size or deploy to a different location or zones. See https://aka.ms/azureskunotavailable for details.'.'. (Code: InvalidTemplateDeployment)
```

How do I find out what the issue is?

Comment: Did you go to the link provided in the message: https://aka.ms/azureskunotavailable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the fact that i was selectiong the Spot services check box . all working now

Answer (score 0):

Error says you need to change the location for spinning up VM. Location, 'EastUs' you are trying, could not be used by your subscription. Hit on the link presented in error message to check list of available region you can go with. Best of luck. Thanks, Kasam Shaikh.

Comment: I am using a student account I dont understand what areas or disk sizes and types I am applowed?

Comment: I understand, but it's not about the sizes, error message says it's all about location your selecting for resource provisioning. Change the location, and try again. Thanks

Comment: It was the fact that i was selectiong the Spot services check box . all working now